# how to convert .iif file to .csv file in visual foxpro?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I need to convert .iif file to .csv file in visual FoxPro can you please let me know the code, I have no idea how to do this, can someone please help.

Comment: It can't be done in Visual Foxpro, it's not a supported file type. You'll have to convert it to another file type that VFP can use.

Comment: how to convert a cursor into excel format in visual foxpro?

Comment: @HerbWolfe, iif is a text file format, no? Why would it "can't be done in Visual Foxpro" ???? That is an incorrect statement. It can be done if someone pays for it.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Is it? I wasn't able to find a specific description of the format. Maybe it can be done, but it would certainly be much easier to use the Intuit program that created it, to save it in another format.

Comment: @HerbWolfe, "much easier", you are right on that. I was only concerned on the "can't be done" part. There is an SDK that give sample files + header format help in HTM format. If you just check the files themselves, without reading any SDK help, you would see that it is some sort of multiple tables are bundled together like a TAB delimited data file.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Microsoft Excel, and go to the File menu.
Click New, and select Blank workbook.
Click the File menu, and select Open.
Go to the folder location, and look for the file name. You can set the file type to All Files so you can easily find the IIF file.
Click Open.
Go to the File menu, and click Save As.
Choose a location to save the file, and enter the file name. Make sure the Save as type is Excel Workbook.
Click Save.